# Angular JS checkbox - model doesn't default to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two checkboxes in my Angular JS form, like this...

```
<input id="isBackground" type="checkbox" ng-model="addTemplate.data.isBackground">
<input id="repeats" type="checkbox" ng-model="addTemplate.data.repeats">
```

If I tick both boxes then write the $scope to the console, both values are set to true, but if I only tick one of them then one appears in the $scope (set to true) and the other one is simply missing. It should be in the $scope and set to 'false' surely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a property assigned to `ng-model` is **undefined**, ng-model will **automatically create the property after the value is changed for the first time**. It means from second time on, you will see both properties.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wlfyqtcSp4eph5TOWPUo?p=preview)

To avoid this, you could set the default `false` for both properties:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isBackground = false;
  $scope.repeats = false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bo0KSTIlUG9JwV6TvmGP?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Khanh, I'm surprised they made it that way, and it does cause some problems, but your solution worked. I wonder why they chose to bind it to the model only after you've checked it then unchecked it. Nobody would do that with a checkbox and having to set a default on the scope makes it very difficult to create dynamic form. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You're referencing their `id`s for each `input`, is that intended?

Comment: @Shawn Strickland: no, the `ids` are not necessary, copied and pasted from the question, forgot to remove them.

Comment: neat but doesn't really work if the check boxes are created dynamically

Comment: @Astronaut: What do you mean by "created dynamically"? Do you use `ng-repeat` to generate the checkboxes dynamically or just insert a html snippet. In later case, you need to compile your snippet ($compile service)

Comment: If ng-repeat is used to create them and they have dynamic names, see my answer. In this case you don't know the scope values, so you cant set them to false. In my case the forms are being generated dynamically using a json object that has a type, one of the types is checkbox and it also has a name. it can be checkBoxA, checkBoxB, optionA, optionB, bob, etc... you don't know in advance so you cant do $scope.(valuefromJSON)=false. In summary if i generate dynamic forms (strings, checkboxes, etc) i can't have the logic in the controller as per your example ng-init is nicer.

Comment: @Astronaut: Your case is another problem. It's really not related to this question. For each problem, we have a specific solution and design. BTW, I believe we can do anything in controller which we can do in `ng-init`, it's just the matter of where you put your initialization code. BTW, your usage of `ng-init` is not recommended: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Its the same problem, i want to set a checkbox to false by default! In case the forms are being dynamically generated. I think this is the perfect case to use ngInit, its closer to the view than to the model. Another option would be to do it after you receive the data in the .then() to change to false, and that would be more generic than your solution. Your solution only works for static checkboxes, that is all i am saying, there is nothing wrong with it, the solution I wrote works for both static and dynamic.

Comment: @Astronaut: `its closer to the view than to the model` => the value of the checkbox is the model and the appropriate place to set its default value is the controller, not the view. ngInit as in the documentation says:  `such as for aliasing special properties` so that it's easier to manipulate the view, But it's not appropriate to set model default value.

Comment: Sorry i don't agree with you. The whole point of ngInit "The ng-init directive initializes application data." i am initializing the values of the checkboxes. The whole point of directives to me is to have a declarative way of setting values (its a VIEW-MODEL after all). It makes more sense to see that the checkbox is "false" next to its declaration and not having to dig the controller for the value, it can be "false" or whatever value like "Disagree". What would be the need for directives (view-models) if you only use MVC? I prefer the MVVM way you prefer the MVC way.

Answer (score 10):

A more flexible solution is to set a ng-init value, this works for dynamic proprieties as well as fixed, something that the accepted solution does not do.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-init="formData[field.checkBox]=false" ng-model="formData[field.checkBox]">{{field.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Love it - +1 dynamic properties.

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ngTrueValue`,  and `ngFalseValue`. I have use `1/0` use it accordingly

```
<input id="isBackground" ng-true-vale="1" ng-false-value="0" type="checkbox" ng-model="addTemplate.data.isBackground">
<input id="repeats" ng-true-vale="1" ng-false-value="0" type="checkbox" ng-model="addTemplate.data.repeats">
```

From [Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.checkbox)

> ngTrueValue: The value to which the expression should be set when selected.
>
> ngFalseValue: The value to which the expression should be set when not selected.

### OR

You can use [**ngChecked**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked), If the expression is truthy, then special attribute "checked" will be set on the element

```
<input id="isBackground" ng-checked="addTemplate.data.isBackground == true" type="checkbox" ng-model="addTemplate.data.isBackground">
<input id="repeats" ng-checked="addTemplate.data.repeats == true" type="checkbox" ng-model="addTemplate.data.repeats">
```

Comment: I tried setting both to ng-false-value="false", but if you don't tick them they don't appear in the model. If you tick them both and untick them, then they appear in the model.

Comment: I want them both to appear in the model, even before you have ticked or un-ticked them.

Comment: Does that work 2 ways though? I know it will check the box if the model is set to true, but by default will it put it in the model and set it to false before the user interacts with the checkbox. I'm not sure you understand my original question.

Comment: Sorry Satpal but that still doesn't work. If I submit the form without ticking either of them then they are missing from the model. If I tick both of them then they both appear in the model. It is like they are defaulting to null instead of false.

Comment: Thanks for your help Satpal, but Khanh seems to have found the problem.